# image inserted for image button is not visible

Tags: visual-studio-2008, imagebutton, visual-web-developer

I have made a webpage for taking a date for a textbox using calendar. I have used Imagebutton to show the calendar. When we click that Imagebutton, calendar will show up. I have used a calendar image for that image button, but when i run the program the image which I have attached with the Imagebutton is not visible in the web browser. I am using visual studio 2008 and c# as programming language and chrome as the default web browser. Please help me in the case. I have attached the HTML code which I am using.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1"
            runat="server" Height="39px" ImageUrl="~/App_Data/Calen.jpeg" 
            Width="70px" onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />
    <br />
        <asp:Calendar ID="Cal1" runat="server" 
            onselectionchanged="Cal1_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: please anybody give solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your browser do not support the option. Try ro debug the same solution in other browsers like mozila firefox or safari. That might be helpful